# In what direction(s) is any debris typically ejected from a jet engine in the case of failure during flight?

Tags: jet-engine

Has there been evidence of ejected material striking the fuselage or other parts of an aircraft forward of the engine itself?

Which of the various forces acting on rotor blades dominates the trajectory of pieces in the case of a blade failure?

Other than rotor break-up, what kinds of engine malfunction typically cause component separation, and in what direction(s) is material ejected?

Comment: There are many studies on the topic of uncontained engine failure. e.g.: [Large Engine Uncontained Debris Analysis](http://www.tc.faa.gov/its/worldpac/techrpt/AR99-11.pdf), or [Uncontained Engine Debris Analysis Using the Uncontained Engine Debris Damage Assessment Model](http://www.tc.faa.gov/its/worldpac/techrpt/AR04-16.pdf),  and [Uncontained Engine Failure](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Uncontained_Engine_Failure).

Comment: There is one crash I can think of, where the engine itself separated, traveled forward and struck the leading edge of the wing. This was [American Air Flight 191](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_191).

Comment: [QF32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32#Cause) had an uncontained engine failure in which debris went in multiple directions, but by pure luck avoided the fuselage.

Comment: Technically speaking, AA191 was not an engine failure. It was a pylon fuse pin failure due to faulty maintenance techniques, leading to partial and then total separation of the pylon with engine attached. The engine was working just fine when it pivoted upward and then over the wing due to pylon separation, tearing out the leading edge flap.

Answer (score 2):

For debris ejection out of the engine, the failure of the engine and the failures that follow that create debris; the design criteria is that the failures must be contained in the cowling and the debris exits through the exhaust. Here is the link to the FAA Advisory Circular for designing for catastrophic failure: [AC 20-128A](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_20-128A.pdf)

Here is another link that is more devoted to prior [uncontained engine failure](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Uncontained_Engine_Failure).

Comment: Debris *should* be contained (and there is a check for this to certify the engine). However they are not always, so the accidents, I think the question is about the latter cases, not what is expected (to some extent).

Answer (score 0):

When the fan disk failed during [UA232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_232), there was damage forward of the fan disk itself.  See also the associated damage [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UA232damage.png).  While this was not forward of the engine nacelle, it seems to address the intent of the question.